# How to dynamically import classes?

Tags: javascript

I've three js files `file_a.js` , `file_b.js` & `file_c.js`, they all have a class called `Context`:

```
export class Context{
constructor(){
...
}
Other_functions_which_are_different_for_each_file(){
...
}
}
```

Based on the argument passed in `index.js`, I'm calling the `Context` class from the relevant file.

`index.js`:

```
let call = document.currentScript.getAttribute("call");
let {Context} = import('./file'.concat(call));
...
async function app(){
camera = new Context();
}
```

The problem is `index.js` doesn't recognise `Context` as a class. So, I'm getting `Context is not a constructor` error on the line `camera = new Context();`.

How can I import the `Context` class, such that I'm not block scoped & can call the class inside the `app()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic imports return a promise, so you will need to wait for that promise before you can use `Context`. For example:

```
const importPromise = import('./file'.concat(call));
...
async function app() {
  const { Context } = await importPromise;
  camera = new Context();
}
```